# How to check If table contains diferent values?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have table:

```
Id Value
1  79868
2  79868
3  79868
4  97889
5  97889
```

Now, I want to make next select with bool variable that check if table contains difrent values at table column `Value`. Something like this:

```
 select  
        v= (select case when exists(...)
                    then 1 
                    else 0
                    end)
```

Table contais Values: 79868, 97889 so `v` should return 1 in other case 0.
How to write select iniside select case??

Comment: How do you want `NULL` values to be handled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare the min and max values:

```
select (case when (select min(value) from t) = (select max(value) from t)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as all_same
```

With an index on `(value)`, this should be quite fast.

The above solution assumes that there are no `null` values or that `NULL` values should be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You might try this:

```
SELECT CASE COUNT(*)
         WHEN 1 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
       END AS all_equal
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Value FROM my_table);
```

Comment: Works even if there are NULLs.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correct, you want to check if value column contains more than 1 distinct values. You can achieve this using,

```
select (case when count(value) > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as out 
from (select value from table group by value)  temp
```

Comment: Works even if there are NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

So, you just need one `case` expression with two Boolean variable

```
declare @bit1 bit = 1, @bit0 bit = 0

select 
      (case when min(value) = max(value) then @bit1 else @bit0 end) as v 
from table t
where value is not null
```

Comment: Assumes there are no NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

May this is better:

```
SELECT CASE COUNT(DISTINCT value) WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
       END AS all_equal
FROM   my_table;
```

Comment: Assumes there are no NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a the same as another answers
But is has some test data

```
declare @T table(pk int identity primary key, val int not null);
insert into @T (val) values (79868), (79868), (79868);
select case when count(distinct(val)) = 1 then 0 else 1 end as dd 
  from @t t;
select case when min(val) = max(val) then 0 else 1 end as dd 
  from @t t;
insert into @T (val) values (97889), (97889);
select case when count(distinct(val)) = 1 then 0 else 1 end as dd 
  from @t t;
select case when min(val) = max(val) then 0 else 1 end as dd 
  from @t t;
```

I like the min max answer from Gordon best